# How to properly and effective rename a vaue (column) of a foreign key in both tables?

Tags: postgresql, performance, foreign-key

I have 2 tables: `users` and `user_statuses`. A user status is of type `varchar`. It's varchar for the purpose of readability and I don't consider using id/int in this case.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
 --............
 status varchar foreign key references user_statuses(name),
 --.....
```

The column `name` in `user_statuses` is UNIQUE

At some point I may need to rename some the name or names of some statuses in `user_statuses` table because I haven't decided what to name them and how many of the statuses overall I need.

**Question:** How would I rename a status name such that it's effective in terms of performance? And in general, how to do it properly in this case?

P.S.

In my real system I have dozens of `_*statuses` tables and each is subject to have some of its statuses renamed.

Each of the tables that refers to `*_statuses` ones may have, say, 10M-30M-50M rows. Or up to 100M ones at most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using a code for the status. I.e

```
CREATE TABLE USER_STATUS
( STATUS_CODE CHAR(?) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, STATUS_NAME TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

The use of char is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29_even_for_fixed-length_identifiers) by the postgres community, so an alternative would be to use text and an additional constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_STATUS
( STATUS_CODE TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, STATUS_NAME TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
,     CHECK (LENGTH(STATUS_CODE) <= ?)
);
```

It should be more stable than the name, but more intuitive than an int.

But for your question, I would probably insert the new value:

```
INSERT INTO USER_STATUS (NAME) VALUES ('Valid');
```

then update all users:

```
UPDATE USERS SET STATUS = 'Valid' WHERE STATUS = *Normal';
```

and finally, remove the old status:

```
DELETE FROM USER_STATUS WHERE NAME = 'Normal';
```

For the more general case where there is a hierarchy of tables involved, you traverse them in DFS and insert new rows on the way down. When you reach a leaf you can use update and then delete rows as you climb the tree back up. You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` to obtain the edges in the tree, and then use for example a topological sort to determine the ordering of the tables.

Another advice is to stick with the same name for the attribute throughout the model. I.e:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_STATUS
( STATUS_CODE ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, STATUS_NAME TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE USERS
( ...
, STATUS_CODE ... REFERENCES USER_STATUS (STATUS_CODE)
...
);
```

Comment: you mean, not to rename in place but create a new  status value and then update all old values in `users` to point to it? If yes, it'll work

Comment: Yes, thats the idea

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ENUM type and use that as the column type (instead of varchar) in both tables.  Then you can use `ALTER TYPE status_type RENAME VALUE...` to change the spelling of one of the type's values in a performant way.

Comment: You created a new enum type and removed the foreign key. Why will "user_statuses" be needed at all thereafter?

Comment: I assumed user_statuses had additional columns, like longer-form names, names in other languages, owner/permissions fields, etc., which you wanted to keep.  (In which case, you might still want to have the foreign key, it would just be between enum types rather than text types).  If you don't need more columns, by all means get rid of the user_statuses table.

Comment: How would you ensure that data between the Enum and "user_statuses" is  identical at all times?